# what could limit bytes read in from read()

Tags: sockets

I am reading bytes off a socket initialised like this:

```
fd = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
```

However when I read from this socket

```
char buf[ETH_FRAME_LEN]
len = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
```

len shows only 1500 bytes were read. I checked with wireshark and the packet returned is 5854. The total length field under IP says 5840 (so + 14 bytes for ethernet header = 5854). I tried using a larger buffer (6000) but still only 1500 bytes were being read off the wire.

I tried requesting a smaller file from the server (1504 bytes), but I get the same results. As it is a raw socket, the data read in includes the ethernet headers, so it is not reading the last 4 bytes into the buffer.

What could be the cause of this? I'm not aware of any argument to `socket()` that could cause this.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you try calling `read` again?  Is the next chunk of the message quickly returned?

From the read [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) (my emphasis)

> read() attempts to read ***up to*** count bytes

If you want to read a certain number of bytes, you should be prepared to call `read` in a loop until you receive your target total cumulatively over the calls.

Comment: hhmm, I changed it so I am doing reads into two different buffers. The server sends me two large messages. The first read reads in 1500 bytes of the first message, the second read reads in 1500 bytes of the second message. So I guess this means the bytes that aren't read get discarded. I'd expect this from a SOCK_DGRAM/UDP socket, but is this normal for a RAW socket?

Comment: I doubt the data has been discarded.  You'll probably find there is more data available to read if you try again.

Comment: Hhmm the reads I did were:
    len = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
    len2 = read(fd, buf2, sizeof(buf2));
That is, two successive reads from the same fd. Is this what you meant by try again?

Comment: Yep.  Or you could declare a single large buffer and loop, changing the point within the buffer that is written to on each call, until you have read your target amount of data

Comment: In case you haven't noticed it, Zaffy has provided an example of the sort of loop I was talking about below.

Comment: Thanks, but when I tested two successive reads() as in the comment above, the contents of the buf were the first 1500 bytes of the first message and the contents of buf2 were the first 1500 bytes of the second message, not the unread bytes from the first message.

Comment: Sorry, I'd missed that key part of your comment.  I can't explain that behaviour I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that you're getting exactly one Ethernet [MTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit)'s worth of payload per call to `read()`.

Comment: But as it is a RAW socket, shouldn't I be getting the entire 1514 bytes (ie ethernet MTU of 1500 + ethernet header of 14)?

Answer (score 1):

`read()` returns:

> On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end of
>          file), and the file position is advanced by this number.  **It is not  an
>          error  if  this  number  is smaller than the number of bytes requested**;
>          this may happen for example because fewer bytes are actually  available
>          right  now  (maybe  because we were close to end-of-file, or because we
>          are reading from a pipe, or from a terminal),  or  because  read()  was
>          interrupted  by  a  signal.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set
>          appropriately.  In this case it is left unspecified  whether  the  file
>          position (if any) changes.

You can try to use `recv()` with **MSG_WAITALL** instead of pure `read()`:

> This flag requests that  the  operation  block  until  the  full
>                 request  is  satisfied.  However, the call may still return less
>                 data than requested if a signal is caught, an error  or  disconnect  occurs,  or the next data to be received is of a different
>                 type than that returned.

```
len = recv(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), MSG_WAITALL);
```

Another way is to read or recv in a loop like:

```
ssize_t Recv(int fd, void* buf, ssize_t n)
{
    ssize_t read = 0;
    ssize_t r;
    while(read != n)
    {
        r = recv(fd, ((char*)buf)+read, n-read, 0);
        if(r == -1)
            return (read) ? read : -1;
        if(r == 0)
            return 0;

        read += r;
    }

    return read;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. When I do multiple reads from the same socket, the first read() reads in the first 1500 bytes from the first message; the second read() reads in the first 1500 bytes from the second message, not the first message.

Comment: @AG yes, it is possible, limit can be also in socket option rcvbuf, that specifies maximum length of bytes can be waiting for read/recv. Did you tried the msg_waitall and/or read in a loop?

Comment: Hi, I checked rcvbuf, it is 112640 bytes, so that wouldn't be the problem.
When doing multiple reads (for example in a loop), the recv call reads in the first 1500 bytes from the next ethernet frame, not the unread bytes from the original frame.